# How to use Task.Delay() in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# and I want to try `Task.Delay()` in my codes, but I got some errors.

This is my codes:

```
static public void Main(string[] args)
{
    Delay();
}

static async Task Delay()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
}
```

This is the error I got:

> The statement is not awaited and execution of current method continues before the call is completed. Consider using 'await' operator or calling 'Wait' method

It doesn't print every number per second, maybe I'm doing it the wrong way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler is warning you that you are calling an `async` method but you are now `await`ing it, so doing anything with the returned `Task`.

Make your `Main` method `async` and `await` on the call to `Delay`:

```
static public async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    await Delay();
}

static async Task Delay()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer solves my problems. :) I finished the lessons on Codecademy but it doesn't teach me how to use `async/await` and `Task` so I had no idea what was going on in my codes XD.